# Limit array size to 1MB in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following operation that I'm doing in BigQuery:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(state IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 10000) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY state
```

What would be the best way to limit the result to be no larger than 1MB? Previously I was doing a LIMIT within the ARRAY_AGG, but often that would exceed the limit if there were large text fields, so I'd prefer to limit it by the ending result size.

Comment: Your query doesn't actually make sense.  You are aggregating by `state` *and* making that the argument to `array_agg()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, right, this is just a made up example, it will show something like `ca,ca,ca,ca,ca...`

Comment: @David542 - were you ever able to evaluate/try option i provided in my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the option (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT state, SUM(LENGTH(state)) OVER(ORDER BY pos) size 
  FROM (
    SELECT state, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() pos
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(state IGNORE NULLS)
FROM temp
WHERE size < 1000000
```

You can test, play with above using below dummy example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT REPEAT('a', CAST(100 * RAND() AS INT64)) state
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100))
), temp AS (
  SELECT state, SUM(LENGTH(state)) OVER(ORDER BY pos) size 
  FROM (
    SELECT state, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() pos
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(state IGNORE NULLS)
FROM temp
WHERE size < 5000
```

Comment: Some problems: 1. ROW_NUMBER() OVER() is undefined for unordered partitions. So it doesn't do anything. 2. Since SUM() doesn't have a window_frame clause, it applies to the entire partition. This means it will evaluate to the same value for everything. 3. Although we don't know the type, LENGTH may be incorrect. If this is a string, it should be BYTE_LENGTH. LENGTH gives number of characters.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg - the answer usually as good as question is  - my answer is valid and match exactly what is asked. so you would rather transform your comments and criticism into your own answer - and i will be able to down vote it too if it will not be just perfect!

Comment: I am sorry if I offended. The biggest issue is the SUM() not having a window frame. This would lead to size < 1000000 being either true for everything or true for nothing. I originally upvoted until I realized that. The BYTE_LENTH and ROW_NUMBER() parts are inconsequential.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg - you comments are plain wrong! `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` produces numbering as expected and then there is no any issue with `SUM() OVER(order by pos)` . So your whole point is INCORRECT!!! Consider first testing proposed solution using the example in answer and then commenting like you did. If you will realize you are wrong and will be willing to revert your downvote  - please let me know! And, btw, have in mind  - this is for Google BigQuery and not just abstract sql

Comment: You are correct. Sorry about that. Both the first and second are from my own misunderstanding. SUM() OVER() does as I said but SUM OVER(ORDER BY $something) does the correct thing. ROW_NUMBER() in this case gives row numbers in an arbitrary order... but that doesn't matter since the entire point was to ORDER BY something. I will reverse my downvote if the post is edited and SO allows me. Interestingly, a way to avoid ROW_NUMBER is SUM() OVER(ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING).

Comment: @StephenWeinberg - glad we cleared it. I've just "edited" my answer so you can act accordingly. in any case - thank you for following up on this

Comment: Alright, found docs on this. I had no idea: If the OVER clause contains an ORDER BY clause but no window_frame_clause, then the ORDER BY implicitly defines window_frame_clause as:

RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts